# HashSet does not work correctly, reason or alternatives?

Tags: c#, list, hashset

I have a HashSet with errors, `<Error>ErrorList`.
"Error" has the properties "file" and "block".
So I fill my HashSet with a number of errors, some of which are exactly the same and therefore repeat themselves. The multiple occurrences are completely tolerated by the HashSet. As a last attempt I created a separate list and distincted it: `List<Error> noDupes = ErrorList.Distinct().ToList();`
But also here my list remains unchanged. Why does neither the hashset nor my noDupes list work? Are there alternative solutions?

Here's the important part of my code:

```
        #region Properties
        HashSet<Error> ErrorList { get; set; } = new HashSet<Error>();
        private Stopwatch StopWatch { get; set; } = new Stopwatch();
        private string CSVFile { get; set; } = null;
        int n;
        #endregion
```

```
                    ErrorList.Add(new Error
                    {
                        File = x,
                        Block = block
                    }); ;
                    
                    

                    n = FileCall.IndexOf(i);
                    int p = n * 100 / FileCall.Count;
                    SetConsoleProgress(n.ToString("N0"), p);
                }
            } 

            int nx = 0;
            List<Error> noDupes = ErrorList.Distinct().ToList();
```

The Error-Class:

```
namespace ApplicationNamespace
{
    public class Error
    {
        public string File { set; get; }
        public int Block { set; get; }
    }
}
```

Comment: probably because your class has no implementation for a hashcode? How should a **hash**-based collection automatically compute a meaningful hash if you don´t provide any information for that hashcode?

Comment: Please post the definition of `Error`. The `HashSet` class cannot automagically know what you consider "equal" or a "duplicate". Show your definition.

Comment: Consider that only because two objects share the same values for some properties does not make those objects equal. Otherwise two persons named John would be the same person, what they pretty sure are not. You have to provide to your program what equality means for you.

Comment: Add an override of the `Equals` and the `GetHashCode` methods, or implement the `IEquatable<Error>` interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the default `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` implementations (like the others have mentioned in the comments) for the `HashSet<>` or `Distinct()` to work. You can also implement `IEquatable<>`, which will require you to override the `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` methods.

```cs
public class Error : IEquatable<Error>
{

    public string File { set; get; }
    public int Block { set; get; }


    public bool Equals(Error other)
    {

        // Check whether the compared object is null.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(other, null)) return false;

        // Check whether the compared object references the same data.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;

        // Check whether the error's properties are equal.
        return File == other.File && Block == other.Block;
    }

    // If Equals() returns true for a pair of objects
    // then GetHashCode() must return the same value for these objects.
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return $"{Block}-{File}".GetHashCode(); // adjust this as you see fit
    }
}
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netcore-3.1

Remember to handle `null` values on the `File` string. (Could replace it with `String.Empty` for instance.) It's also common to "cache" the hashcode in a private variable, so that once calculated the cached value can be returned on consequent calls to `GetHashCode()`. For this you will most likely also need to make the class immutable.

(You won't have to do any of this with C# 9's record types.)